# Does heap size consumption accumulate across chained asynchronous threads?

Tags: apex, queueable-apex

For asynchronous transactions, such as queueable jobs, the heap size limit is 12mb. Let's say I chain 2 queueable threads together. If I pass records queried in the first thread to the constructor in the 2nd thread, does the heap size reset or accumulate? What about for schedulable jobs and chained platform event threads?

Comment: No. Chained async transactions each get their own limits since each is a unique transaction. Note that platform event apex trigger subscribers are not actually considered async apex and get the synchronous limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables are stored in the heap, so if you take the data from the first queueable job, make it available to the second queueable job, *and have the second queueable job query additional data on top of that*, it'll naturally take more heap space than the first queueable job did.

Each queueable job gets its own set of governor limits.

An example, assuming that you carry over all data queried in the constructor from one job to the next.

| Queueable job # | Data passed to constructor | Queried in constructor | other heap data | Total heap |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | none | 10 kb | 50 kb | 60 kb |
| 2 | 10 kb | 10 kb | 30 kb | 50 kb |
| 3 | 20 kb | 10 kb | 40 kb | 70 kb |

The "other heap data" represents other variables and data that you use within a queueable job, but isn't transferred to the next job. Those are just arbitrary numbers that don't mean much of anything.

My purpose here was to help illustrate that what you are describing means that you do have some amount of heap space that is accumulating, but subsequent jobs aren't going to "inherit" *all* of the data you have on the heap from a previous job.

Comment: The queueable receiving the data does not have to receive a copy; the heap space at the time of enqueuement is not double that before. Use, the queueable state data gets cloned into the database, but that does not contribute to heap space.

Comment: @PhilW My reading of OP's question is that data _is being passed_ to subsequent queueable jobs (the whole "I'm passing stuff into the constructor" bit).

Answer (score 0):

In Salesforce, if you chain two queueable jobs together, the heap size will accumulate, which means that the second job will have  seperate other than heap size used by the first job.

This is also true for schedulable jobs and chained platform event threads.

It's important to keep in mind the heap size limits when chaining jobs or threads together. You can use techniques such as selective queries, limiting the number of records processed in each job, or optimizing your code to reduce the amount of heap space used, to ensure that you don't hit the heap size limit and cause your job or thread to fail.